# How to match Array Key name with another Array Key name

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have 2 Array, both Array has common is Director_id to match

I am trying to map key of one Array with  values of another array.

```
$invest_details = DB::table('directors_invest')
    ->join('directors', 'directors.id', '=', 'directors_invest.director_id')
    ->select('directors_invest.*', 'directors.name as directors_name')
    ->get();
##

$expense_details = DB::table('receipts')
    ->join('directors', 'directors.id', '=', 'receipts.director_id')
    ->join('account_type', 'account_type.id', '=', 'receipts.type')
    ->join('expense_type', 'expense_type.id', '=', 'receipts.exp_earn_type')

    ->select('receipts.*', 'directors.name as directors_name', 'account_type.name as account_name', 'expense_type.name as exp_name')
    ->get();

//dd($expense_details);

$director  = DB::table('directors')->get();
$directors = [];
foreach ($director as $value) {
    $directors[$value->id] = $value->name;
}

// Here I will map Director_id and total invest
$investor_total_by_id = [];

foreach ($expense_details as $exp) {
    if (isset($investor_total_by_id[$exp->director_id])) {
        $investor_total_by_id[$exp->director_id] += $exp->amount;

    } else {
        $investor_total_by_id[$exp->director_id] = $exp->amount;

    }
}

dd($investor_total_by_id);
//this gives me out put
//
//      array:2 [▼
//  1 => 7100.0
//  2 => 444.0
//        ]

//** Match Convert Director_id to Director Name. so it will be
//     Director1 => 7100
//     Director2 => 440

$director_id_name_map = [];

foreach ($director as $value) {
    foreach ($investor_total_by_id as $key => $id_value) {

        if (key($investor_total_by_id) == $director[$value->id]) {

            $director_id_name_map[$directors->name] = $investor_total_by_id[$id_value->amount];

        }

    }
}

//dd($investor_total_by_id);
dd($$director_id_name_map);

return view('Accounts/Investment/add')
    ->with('invest_details', $invest_details)
    ->with('expense_details', $expense_details)
    ->with('directors', $directors)
    ->with('investor_total_by_id', $investor_total_by_id)

;
}
```

see the output of 2 Array

the output of $investor_total_by_id

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => 7100.0
  2 => 444.0
]
```

The output $director

```
Collection {#531 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#533 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"name": "Directror1"
      +"phone": ""
      +"email": ""
      +"address": "hi"
      +"created_at": "2019-04-18 13:10:04"
      +"updated_at": "2019-04-18 07:10:04"
    }
    1 => {#534 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"name": "Director2"
      +"phone": ""
      +"email": ""
      +"address": "hi"
      +"created_at": "2019-04-18 14:35:56"
      +"updated_at": "2019-04-18 07:10:04"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looking to create a table in Blade where it will be

```
Director1 7100
Direcot2  440
```

the table will be below

```
<table border=1>
    <th> Director Name </th>
    <th> Amount</th>
    <td> Director1 <td>
    <td>
    <td> 7100 </td>
    <td> Director2 <td>
    <td>
    <td> 440 </td>
<table>
```

Comment: You could do this with a query itself than achieving this with PHP. Can you explain your queries and what are you trying to do?

Comment: @vivek_23 , Thanks, Yes, thats what I was thiking, there might be a easy way by using SQL query, I am using Laravel, basically , I have 2 Table,  director_name(id,name),  Receipts ( id,exp_earn_type,amount,diretor_id) , I am trying achive,   Which Director has expense how much , Currenlty i can get this as Director Id and amount, just need to map it by Director name and amount .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so based on your comments, I am considering below as your DB tables.

> director_name(id,name)
>
> receipts(id,exp_earn_type,amount,director_id)

- So, first we inner join both tables and get the total expense of each director using `sum()`.
- Then we inner join the previous subquery with `director_name` table to get the director names with their other details as well.

**Code:**

```
<?php

    $director_expenses = DB::table('receipts')
                         ->join('director_name','receipts.director_id','=','director_name.id')
                         ->select('receipts.director_id', DB::raw('sum(receipts.amount) as total_expense'))
                         ->groupBy('receipts.director_id');
    
    $director_details = DB::table('director_name')
                        ->joinSub($director_expenses, 'director_expenses', function ($join) {
                            $join->on('director_name.id', '=', 'director_expenses.director_id');
                        })
                        ->select('director_name.id','director_name.name','director_expenses.total_expense')
                        ->get();
    
    dd($director_details);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse directors array and then on the way of looping, you can meet `$investor_total_by_id` by doing handshake with the help of `director_id` and then extracting data from it like below.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Director Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($directors as $key => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $investor_total_by_id[$value->id] }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

**EDIT**

```
return view('foldername.viewname', compact('directors', 'investor_total_by_id'));
```

You can call view like above along with compacting both the arrays.

**EDIT 2**

```
$director_id_name_map = [];
foreach ($directors as $key => $value) {
    $director_id_name_map[$value] = $investor_total_by_id[$key];
}
```

By Above code you can map your expectations in controller.

[compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) — Create array containing variables and their values

Comment: thanks I am writting into Controller, then from Controller i will need to pass the values to blade, 
in Conroller, how will i map id from director Array ( which comming from table) and investor_total_by_id array 
`
$director_id_name_map=[];
      
      foreach ($director as  $key => $value) {
          
            // How do i map id from director Array with id with   $investor_total_by_id     ?  
             
              
          
          }
`

Comment: @alammd Once check my **EDIT 2** portion of answer.

Comment: Please see the content  of $director  in the above question,  just to point it out, i am using varaible $director which comming from database, not $directors[]. ( appologis for bad namming variable) 
so when i use your code it say , "Undefined offset: 2"

Comment: Ohh, okay, changed complete code of edit 2 portion, once refresh this page and check again.

Comment: Thanks, please see the error
"Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"
in this line 
" $director_id_name_map[[$value->name]] = $investor_total_by_id[$value->id];"

Comment: `$director_id_name_map[$value] = $investor_total_by_id[$key];` check this now

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.